# Pyspark explode string column containing JSON nested in array laterally

Tags: python, json, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe containing a column like:

> df['metrics'] =
> [{id=1,name=XYZ,value=3}, {id=2,name=KJH,value=2}]
> [{id=4,name=ABC,value=7}, {id=8,name=HGS,value=9}]

The column is a String type, and I am trying to explode the column using :

```
    from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType

array_item_schema = spark.read.json(df.rdd.map(lambda row: row['metrics'])).schema

json_array_schema = ArrayType(array_item_schema, True)

arrays_df = df.select(F.from_json('metrics', json_array_schema).alias('json_arrays'))

objects_df = arrays_df.select(F.explode('json_arrays').alias('objects'))
```

However, I have a null value returned when I try

```
objects_df.show()
```

The output I am looking for is a separated list of each element in the 'metrics' column, with column names showing id, name, value, in the same dataframe, and don't know where to start to decode it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Check this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/74770833/8773309

Comment: @MohanaBC the code shown here throws an 'invalid syntax' in pyspark...

Comment: that's scala code convert that into python syntax. method names are same in pyspark and spark-scala.

Comment: I have very little exposure to spark scala, and am lost here. Any help would be appreciated in converting that code!

Answer (score 0):

You can schema_of_json function to get schema from JSON string and pass it to from_json function get struct type.

```
  json_array_schema = schema_of_json(str(df.select("metrics").first()[0]))
  arrays_df = df.select(from_json('metrics', json_array_schema).alias('json_arrays'))
```