# How to convert Array<String> to Array<Struct> in spark scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have an Array of JSON String, which I need to parse and convert into a struct.

**transDf** schema:

```
root
 |-- logs: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

This is the code I tried

```
  val logsSchema = new ArrayType(spark.read.json(transDf.select("logs").as[String]).schema, true)
  transDf = transDf.withColumn("logs", from_json(col("logs"), logsSchema))
```

but the above thing only works for string -> struct but not for Array struct.

How can I convert the array for JSON string into `Array<Struct>` without knowing the schema of the JSON.

Comment: Can you print a few rows of your `transDf` dataframe? This will help in helping you :)

Comment: I don't know if it is ok to add a dynamic link in the question with a lot of data. So, here are the transDf.select("logs").show(3, false) without table borders
https://appp.me/aMhbvo 
Hoping, this will be helpfull

Comment: I suppose that you have n json representations in  the array. Is the number of elements fixed in the array?

Comment: No, it's not fixed

Comment: More importantly, do all elements of the array share the same schema? I.e. can you [posexplode](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions$.html#posexplode(e:org.apache.spark.sql.Column):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) it, and then apply schema generated from one row to all of them?

Answer (score 1):

You can [schema_of_json](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#schema_of_json) function to get schema from JSON string and pass it to from_json function get struct type.

```
  val logsSchema = schema_of_json(transDf.select(col("logs").cast("string")).as[String].first())
  transDf = transDf.withColumn("logs", from_json(col("logs"), logsSchema))
```

Comment: .as[String] throws error
AnalysisException: Cannot up cast e.logs from array<string> to string.

Comment: If you want to go ahead with this approach you can change the the type of array column to string.

Comment: Then in the second line also I have to cast as string that will increase the compuataion. isn't it?